# accessing a mapping variable in solidity contract by web3.py

Tags: solidity, web3.py

I'm trying to get the mapping variables of user in this code put it it don't work with `user_detail['firstName']`

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract CustmerAuth {
    uint256 public value;

    constructor() public {}

    struct UserDetail {
        address addr;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        string DoB;
        string phone;
        string email;
        string password;
        bool isUserLoggedIn;
        bool isUserRegister;
    }

    mapping(address => UserDetail) user;

    // user registration function
    function register(
        address _address,
        string memory _firstName,
        string memory _lastName,
        string memory _DoB,
        string memory _Phone,
        string memory _password,
        string memory _email
    ) public returns (bool) {
        // Check if there is no entry in the user mapping for the address
        if (user[_address].isUserRegister == false) {
            require(user[_address].addr != msg.sender);
            user[_address].addr = _address;
            user[_address].firstName = _firstName;
            user[_address].lastName = _lastName;
            user[_address].DoB = _DoB;
            user[_address].phone = _Phone;
            user[_address].password = _password;
            user[_address].email = _email;
            user[_address].isUserLoggedIn = false;
            user[_address].isUserRegister = true;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you’re trying to access the firstName element of of the values in the user mapping. If so,you first need to use the correct address key (addressWhichIsTheKey here) then, to access the elements of a struct, use a dot: `user[addressWhichIsTheKey].firstName`